# change permission for all contents in folder

Tags: command-line

I am following this YouTube tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WN4K8o1aILA&t=2223s about using Linux from scratch to make a Linux distribution everything works except around the 37:04 mark I am doing the chown command and when I do it his way of Sudo chown -R user:distbuild OsName I found that only the user can make and remove files but if you do it the other way so distbuild:user then distbuild can make and remove files but the user can’t. Why is this happening and how can I fix it any help is greatly greatly appreciated

Steps I have tried:I went back over and over tried doing it logged in as the distbuild user and not and even doing everything else again

Comment: Sudo chown -R username ./foldername

Comment: the problem is that I need to make it accessible to two users not just one

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/a/967530/1698042

Comment: @TalaatEtman I tried the answer but the same thing happens

Comment: distbuild related to groupe not user

Comment: see this answer https://askubuntu.com/questions/904903/how-to-allow-two-users-to-access-one-directory-tried-groups-but-failed

Comment: @TalaatEtman I tried that and it just made it worst now I cant even go in to that directory

Comment: wait nvm it works now I just play around with some commands that the answers used thank you @TalaatEtman

Comment: wait no now it only works for a one directory not all the subdirectories